# How to change color dynamically in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to dynamically change color to some elements. Is there a way to get colors using a variable? Something like

```
Colors[myvar] where myvar = "green"
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try to implement the solution of the problem and ask a specific question with a description of what errors you have

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is have a list of colors that you want like this -

```
    static const List<_MyColor> myBgColors = const <_MyColor>[
     const _MyColor(null, 'Clear'),
     const _MyColor(const Color(0xFFFFC100), 'Orange'),
     const _MyColor(const Color(0xFF91FAFF), 'Light Blue'),
     const _MyColor(const Color(0xFF00D1FF), 'Cyan'),
     const _MyColor(const Color(0xFF00BCFF), 'Cerulean'),
     const _MyColor(const Color(0xFF009BEE), 'Blue'),
  ];
```

Here _MyColor is a class like -

```
class _MyColor {
  const _MyColor(this.color, this.name);

  final Color color;
  final String name;
}
```

You can then use this list to access the colors in view you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can I add different colors in listview .Please help me solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712508/how-to-add-different-gradient-colors-to-this-flutter-listview

Answer (score 4):

## 1. Using a Function

You could use functions with a `Color` parameter, i.e., the type of the input parameter would be `Color`. For example, in a simple widget:

```dart
Container buildContainer({Color color}) {
  return Container(
    color: color,
  );
}
```

In this block, we specified the `return` type as being the widget `Container` class. And we've also specified a named parameter called `color`, which takes a `Color` type. Later, if we wish to call this function we would do it like this (you might need to replace the `;` for a `,`):

```dart
buildContainer(color: Colors.red);
```

## 2. `final` vs `const`

I still think the question has insufficient description, but, if this answer above didn't solve it, I suspect [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585082/how-do-i-execute-dynamically-like-eval-in-dart) might be of help.

As for the keyword `final`, it is used when you want to declare constants inside (custom) widgets. That's because widgets will need constants defined at runtime, not at compile-time, like `const`. Otherwise, whenever a widget is destroyed and rebuilt, it wouldn't know how to properly do it if the constant was related to something that happened during runtime. As per [the docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const):

> If you never intend to change a variable, use `final` or `const`, either instead of `var` or in addition to a type. A final variable can be set only once; a const variable is a compile-time constant. (Const variables are implicitly final.) A final top-level or class variable is initialized the first time it’s used.

## 3. Using a Class

For example, another way of doing the same thing I mentioned above, but now creating a new class for a new widget, instead of returning modifications on a widget with a function is:

```dart
class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color customColor;

  CustomContainer({this.customColor});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 10.0,
        width: 10.0,
        color: customColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using `final` works for me.

```
final text_color = Colors.blue;
```

below is an example of how i use it in my class

```
class ColorTest extends StatefulWidget {
  ColorTest();

  @override
  _ColorTest createState() => _ColorTest();
}

class _ColorTest extends State<ColorTest> {

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {

    final my_color_variable = Colors.red; // my_color_variable is now the color red

    return new Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: my_color_variable, // its red
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: with this, if i were to have multiple containers, i can use the variable to color them all. then change the color on the variable to change every container's color that i color this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution.
In my app, 
1. I want the color from the number A to change when I change this value with a slider. 
2. But when I use the slider for the number B I want the color of B the change and that the number A is normal.

What have I done:
I have made constants for my text style:

```
const numbers = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'B612 Mono',
  fontSize: 18.0,
  color: white,
);

const changeValueAB = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'B612 Mono',
  fontSize: 18.0,
  color: cRelayMiddle,
  backgroundColor: white,
);
```

I have made two booleans:

```
bool aActive = false;
bool bActive = false;
```

Then I made two functions:

```
void changeColorA() {
  aActive = true;
  bActive = false;
}

void changeColorB() {
  aActive = false;
  bActive = true;
}
```

Then when I change the values (I take now only as example value A. 
B you just have to place the right void in it:

```
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                    // your commands AND the void the change the booleans:
                      changeColorA();
                    });
                  },
```

Where the textcolor has to change I use:

```
Text(
  '$inputNumberA', 
  style: aActive ? changeValueAB : numbers,),
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

100% working and easy method

just create a variable
final Color myColor;

create a constructor to pass the color dynamically
required this.myColor

print the color
return Container(
color: myColor,
);

Pass the color as like - myColor: Colors.red

Answer (score 0):

**Start with 2 bracket pairs...**

```
color: () (),
```

Then add anonymous function: (){} to the first brackets ...

```
color: ( (){} )   (),
```

Finally add code to it...

```
color: ( (){ if (true) return Colors.green;} )   (),
```

Done