# How to unstringify(convert into a non string) a string in dart?

Tags: dart

`String x = '5 + 6'`

How do I evaluate the string above so that it produces result. 5 + 6 equals 11. How do I get that result from the above string?

Comment: can you help me find that, any clue to the source I should look into? @julemand101

Comment: I have added an answer with example of using two different packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative you can also make use of the [math_expressions](https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions) package:

```
import 'package:math_expressions/math_expressions.dart';

void main() {
  String x = '5 + 6';
  print(solve(x)); // 11
}

int solve(String expr) =>
    (Parser().parse(expr).evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, ContextModel()) as double)
        .toInt();
```

Or use [expressions](https://pub.dev/packages/expressions) which seems to be more simple to use but have fewer features:

```
import 'package:expressions/expressions.dart';

void main() {
  String x = '5 + 6';
  print(solve(x)); // 11
}

int solve(String expr) =>
    const ExpressionEvaluator().eval(Expression.parse(expr), null) as int;
```

Both packages should work with Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:isolate';

void main() async {
  var sumString = '5 + 6';

  final uri = Uri.dataFromString(
    '''
    import "dart:isolate";

    void main(_, SendPort port) {
      port.send($sumString);
    }
    ''',
    mimeType: 'application/dart',
  );

  final port = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawnUri(uri, [], port.sendPort);

  final int response = await port.first;
  print(response);
}
```

This is based on [How do I execute Dynamically (like Eval) in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585082/how-do-i-execute-dynamically-like-eval-in-dart)

Also note:

> Note that you can only do this in JIT mode, which means that the only place you might benefit from it is Dart VM command line apps / package:build scripts. It will not work in Flutter release builds.

Comment: is there any way to integrate it with flutter? Any packages, anything? @Lesiak

Comment: Check my answer: it will NOT work in flutter release build.