# Dart dynamic features, dart:js platform availablility

Tags: dart, dart-html

Is there a dynamic feature of the language available for every platform?

Dart:js is there, however it is not clear if it is only for Web now? Maybe it is possible to call JS VM through `WebView` which in theory should be available everywhere?

The requirement is to compute a formula dynamically, i.e. user enters a way of computation:

- User enters a math formula - think Excel
- User enters a pure function
- User enters a function to modify an object in memory

Is there an approach for every platform with Dart?

Old languages like Java are used to even have native VM implementations of other languages, think Jython or Java JS VM Engine - Rhino, Nashorn (Java has two JS Engine implementations)

Comment: can you show example of formula what you need, I think you talk about `evaluate` it, but what you want to use in it. or do you want a whole `vm`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585082/how-do-i-execute-dynamically-like-eval-in-dart

Comment: You should consider just building your own expression parser with petitparser (in the pub).  Very powerful, but relatively easy to use.  Once you get the hang of it, you may never write another regex again. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz that's a good starting point, thank you!

Comment: @DaniilLoban Any solution for dynamic formula will suffice. I found 
`samurai-dart` pub for JS VM implementation, not sure of the quality though. The linked Isolate approach doesn't seem to work in normal environment, no to say every platform

Comment: @AndreyChaschev will your formulas contain variables and functions from the environment?

Comment: @DaniilLoban ?! No. That is Flutter app with user-defined financial formulas like Excel

Comment: This is good, so I think you can write a string parser (pulling out the variable names) and compute its converted polish notation, which is the best solution in this case in my opinion. For this, your variables must be stored in one place and retrieved from there for substitution. And also you can substitute any math functions.

Comment: also see https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions

Comment: @DaniilLoban Thanks Daniel! What about petitparser suggested above, do you think it can potentially speed you up with your work process?

Comment: @AndreyChaschev I think it would be better not to use third-party libraries, but the decision is yours. Try to implement the solution yourself and if it doesn't work, announce a competition. Сode and conditions used would be helpful.