# convert stringdata to dart code in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
String codeString = 'int a=2; int b=3; int sum=a+b; print("total sum= "); print(sum);';
```

convert the codestring to code & run in flutter project. I want to run the code;
I just tried using **dart:mirrors** but it's not supporting.

Comment: I'm afraid it's simply not possible

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585082/how-do-i-execute-dynamically-like-eval-in-dart

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved
using https://pub.dev/packages/dart_eval

```
String codeString = 'main() {var printdata=[];int a=2; int b=3; int sum=a+b; int div=a-b; printdata.add(sum); printdata.add(div); printdata.add("Hello, World!"); return printdata;';
eval(modifiedString).forEach((item) {
        //you can access the output here. do what ever you want
      });
```